# Call bootstrap typeahead updater function from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scope, typeahead

Is there is a way for me to access the updater function from outside of the typeahead scope ?

My current example is that in the updater function, I have some custom logic that creates some html and appends it to the body such as with the following snippet example:

```
 updater: function(item){
                $input = $('<span/>',{
                   class:'label label-info',
                   text:item,
                   style:'margin-left:4px'
                 });
                ...
                $('#tagContainer').append($input);

             }
```

Now my question is: Is it possible for me to link this function to a button so that it is triggered when the button is clicked, considering that I will pass it the 'item' parameter ?

I guess this problem involves something about functions scope, and this is where my knowledge lack, and need some insight.

Comment: Consider wrapping the `class` with quotes, old browsers throw an error when see reserved words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define it as a separate function:

```
function appendInput(item) {
   //same contents
}

update: appendInput ...

$("button").on('click', function () { appendInput(this); });
```

Comment: So simple... I just learned something about jquery. did not know you could add an external function instead of creating it in place.

Comment: @QuantumLicht correction: you just learned something about *JavaScript*